# Ajax Automatic Div Update w/out page refresh won't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, refresh

I am struggling to figure out why this is not working, but I would like it so that the information from *load.php* is placed in the div *sample* but if that code is updated (say if i was pulling information from a database), only the information included in *load.php* would refresh - not the entire page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">            </script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var callAjax = function(){
      $.ajax({
        method:'get',
        url:'load.php',
        success:function(data){
          $("#sample").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    setInterval(callAjax,5000);
  });
 </script>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id='sample'>100 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting the expected values in success callback?

Comment: The code you have pasted will only update load.php every 5 seconds. To reload the whole page, you must use the following meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">`

Comment: I want it to update JUST load, but it isn't

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation with my AJAX calls. I am not sure if your syntax is actually bad but here is how my Ajax call looks for a similar partial load.

```
 var callAjax = function(){

       $.ajax({
            url: "load.php"
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {

             $("#sample").html(data);
            }
          });
       }
    };

   setInterval(callAjax,5000);
```

I found that my Ajax started working once I added the async:true and made sure my controller was handling GET requests. I had previously forgotten that it was set to HTTPPOST only.

I hope this helps out. Not sure if it will.

cheers.

Comment: unfortunately it still isn't working. but I am running it off of HostGator, so I don't think I can really change too many settings.

Comment: sadly Ajax is a weird beast. I find unique issues with every deployment.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval('someFunc()', 1000);

function someFunc()
{

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "www.domain.com/url",
        data: data,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#myDiv").html(html);                
        }  
    });

}
```